# How to move files and remove hyphens in file names during file move?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a list of files in one folder. I want them renamed and moved into another folder. I want character `-` to be removed from the file name.

For example if file is

```
Some-file-name.jpeg
```

it should be

```
Some file name.jpeg
```

and moved into folder that I choose.

Pretty simple for someone who knows batch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set source=Source Directory
set dest=Destination Directory

for %%a in ("%source%\*") do (
    set file=%%~nxa
    set file=!file:-= !
    move /y "%%a" "%dest%\!file!"
)>nul
```

Comment: +1 but I think the OP needs to delete the dash, not replace it with a space.

Comment: @foxidrive I see. Didn't see that.

Comment: I think this answer is correct. Let me test it and give you a feedback. I want them replaced with blank spaces and not deleted. Please if you changed that put it as it was before.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all the files in current directory with "-" in the file name.

### Example

if current directory contains following files:

- Some-file-name.jpeg
- Some-file-name2.jpeg
- Some-file-name3.jpeg
- SomeFileNameWithoutHyphen.jpeg

All the files with "-" in their filename will be copied to "target" folder in current directory:

So target directory will contain

- Some file name.jpeg
- Some file name2.jpeg
- Some file name3.jpeg

### Code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem ------set the name of the target directory---------------------
set /P target="Enter Destination Folder: "
set /a count=0

rem ------loop through all the filesnames in current directory containing "-" ---------------------
for %%i in ("%cd%\*-*") do (
    echo %%i
    set filename=%%~ni
    rem ------Move to target directory and rename ---------------------
    move /y "%%i" "%target%\!filename!">NUL
    ren "%target%\!filename!" "!filename:-= !"
    set /a count=count+1
)
echo.
echo Moved %count% files
```